# Unable to install watson developer cloud module through pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, ibm-watson

[Getting the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHU0z.png)

Python version: 3.7.3
Pip version: 19.1.1
Installing it from Anaconda prompt.

[Anaconda version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGYZj.png)

Also,
I am running it from VMware horizon client, and I checked from LAN connection settings,no proxy's been set. An early response will help.

Comment: Please click on the 2 links to see the image which contains error message and anaconda version

Comment: The best bet in your case will be to install it from a downloaded tar file
`https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/a5/a89fc49bd82eb6ea569e45b43383c28cd51b5076f43010dcc3331c137ff5/watson-developer-cloud-2.10.1.tar.gz`
and the using pip - `pip install /downloads/watson-developer-cloud-2.10.1.tar.gz `

Comment: If you are getting a timeout for pypi.org, then there is something blocking the network traffic. This is most likely to be a proxy, or a firewall or maybe the machine you run pip on simply does not have visibility of the internet.